In Laravel 11 how can I get the Review data to be displayed in a paginated fashion while still using ReviewCollection?
I've got the following in a App\Http\Resources\V1\BookResource.php that I would like to paginate.
"reviews" => new ReviewCollection(
    $this->reviews()
        ->where("approved", 1)
        ->paginate(7)
),

The result is being returned in a non-paginated format. Only displaying the data like this.
"reviews": [
    {
        "id": 50,
        "rating": "2",
        "text": "Voluptatibus tempora recusandae tenetur aliquid earum rem. Earum nihil qui tenetur. Ea est cupiditate ad sit quaerat. Ducimus voluptas eveniet id sed vel.",
        "user": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Prof. Jerel Gerlach Sr.",
            "email": "bergnaum.stephen@example.net",
            "emailVerifiedAt": "2024-10-23T05:04:07.000000Z",
            "createdAt": "2024-10-23T05:04:24.000000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-10-23T05:04:24.000000Z"
        },
        "createdAt": "2024-10-23T05:04:29.000000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-10-23T05:04:29.000000Z"
    }
    ...
]

How can I get the Review data to be displayed in a paginated fashion while still using ReviewCollection? I can get it to work without the ReviewCollection with the following.
"reviews" => $this->reviews()
    ->where("approved", 1)
    ->paginate(7),

But it really is essential I achieve this with ReviewCollection because I need the attributes to be formatted to the JSON standard.
I have tried this.
"reviews" => new ReviewCollection(
    $this->reviews()
        ->where("approved", 1)
        ->paginate(7)
),

The following works by returning paginated results, however it is not formatted by the ReviewCollection.
"reviews" => $this->reviews()
    ->where("approved", 1)
    ->paginate(7),


I wanted the reviews to be nested in the BookResource. However I have now created a separate getReviewsByBook route that works how I want. By returning the pagination inside the collection, from the controller. This way I can get the paginated results I want. Having a separate request to do this is better practice anyway, being loosely-coupled.

Pagination links with api resources are added at the top level of response, next to data. Did you try just return only new ReviewCollection(...)?

Thanks for your suggestion. After trying that I found that doesn't work either. We get the following JSON response.
"0": [
     {
         "id": 12,
        ...
    }
]```
I am assuming you meant this in the resource file. A flat approach.

...
"approved" => $this->approved,
new ReviewCollection(
$this->reviews()
->where("approved", 1)
->paginate(3)
),```
